# "AttributeError" in a multiple dataframe for to_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with mutations and these are distribuited in 22 different files (working with only 22 chromosomes). While i am saving this files and adding a column (named as chrom) i finally get my multiple data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
path=os.getcwd()
files=glob.glob(path+"/*snp.txt")
li=[]

for file in files:
    df=pd.read_csv(file,index_col=None,names=["pos","ref","AA"], delim_whitespace=True)
    df['chrom']=os.path.basename(file)
    df['chrom']=df.chrom.apply(lambda x: x.replace('snp.txt',''))
    li.append(df)
    li.to_csv(f'chrom{li.iloc[4,0]}_snp.csv')
```

But when i am trying to save this in different dataframes i got this warning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'*
```

I tried using `dataframe=pd.DataFrame(li)` but results as this:

```
 89 pos  ref AA chrom 0 100...
90 pos ref AA chrom 0 100...
91pos  ref AA chrom 0 100...
```

How i convert my multiple dataframes to save em as multiple csv? I mean, save every edited dataframe into different csv files.

Edit: I don't need em concatenated.

Comment: "but results as this" Okay, and *what's wrong with* that result? "How i convert my multiple dataframes to save em as csv?" Well, *what result do you want*? Should the rows from each input be concatenated together? Should it write a separate csv file for each of the multiple dataframes? Something else?

Comment: It should be multiple csv files.

Comment: Oh. Well in that case, just `df.to_csv` once you're done with the changes to `df` each time through the loop, and forget about the list.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why It works... but it works! Thank you!

Comment: It works because each time through the loop, `df` is the name for another dataframe that you want to write to a file, so you... write that dataframe to a file. I don't really know what there is to be confused by.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `li.to_csv()` try [`pd.concat(li).to_csv('path')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)